# React & State to create a timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, setinterval

I am making a timer using React & State only, there is Session time which is set to 2 minutes and Break time, set to 1 minute. When play button is clicked, the timer will start decrementing the value, and when the session time become 0, it will move to break time and when break time become 0, it will move to session time untill the stop button or reset is pressed.

Here I am facing two problems:

1. At first cycle when session time become 0, it moves to break time. but since break time is set to 1 minutes, its not starting from set time. After first cycle its working as expected.
2. When I click Play button repeatedly or twice, then I am not able to pause the timer.

Please find my complete code from [CodePen](https://codepen.io/paldong-creater/pen/dywjXRp)

```
  handleTimer = () => {
      this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
        
        if(this.state.sessionMin == 0 && this.state.Sec == 0){
          clearInterval(this.interval);
          this.setState({
            sessionMin: this.state.sessionConst
          })
       
          this.breakInterval = setInterval(()=>{
            if(this.state.breakMin == 0 && this.state.Sec == 0){
              clearInterval(this.breakInterval);
              this.setState({
                breakMin: this.state.breakConst
                
              })
              console.log(this.state.breakMin)
              this.handleTimer()
            }
            
        
        this.setState({
        display: 'Break',
        Sec: this.state.Sec == 0 ? 10 : this.state.Sec-1,
        breakMin: this.state.Sec == 0 ? this.state.breakMin-1 : this.state.breakMin
      })
            
          },1000)
        }
        
        this.setState({
        display: 'Session',
        Sec: this.state.Sec == 0 ? 10 : this.state.Sec-1,
        sessionMin: this.state.Sec == 0 ? this.state.sessionMin-1 : this.state.sessionMin
      })
      
    },1000)
  }
```

Note: second is set to 10s, instead of 60s for quick test.
Note: Reset button is not functioning yet.
Note: when ever play button is pressed after stop button, it should continue from that state, not to start over again.

I use 'state' to get latest or most recent data, but it did not work. I don't want to try hooks or any other stuff, want to use only simple component level state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If you want to skip explanation and go to solution, scroll down.***

1. Let's say, your session timer reached the state **Session: 0min 0sec**. Look at the code below (with comments):

   ```
    // current state: *Session: 0min 0sec*
    this.interval = setInterval(()=>{
      if (this.state.sessionMin == 0 && this.state.Sec == 0) {
      // You tell a browser API "Stop calling this interval function in 
      // future", but execution of current function call continues !!!
      clearInterval(this.interval)

      // Execution continues, right? So, this.setState.sessionMin 
      // takes value of this.state.sessionConst, that is 2
      this.setState({ sessionMin: this.state.sessionConst })

      // Here you are setting breakInterval, but runtime doesn't care
      // about it for now, because first call of this.breakInterval 
      // will be made after 1000ms
      // (setInterval(() => {}, 1000) 
      // ...wait 1000ms ... 
      // first call 
      // ... wait 1000ns 
      // second call
      // ... etc 
      this.breakInterval = setInterval(()=>{
        // ...breakInterval logic
      },1000)
    }

    this.setState({
      display: 'Session',
      // this.state.Sec == 0, so it's value is set to 10
      Sec: this.state.Sec == 0 ? 10 : this.state.Sec-1,
      // As mentioned above, this.state.sessionMin is 2,
      // so here this.state.sessionMin is set to 1 (2 - 1)
      sessionMin: this.state.Sec == 0 ? this.state.sessionMin-1 : this.state.sessionMin
    })
   },1000)
   ```

So after execution of code above state of your timer is **Session: 1min 10sec**, not **Break: 0min 10sec** as you expected.
Then after 1s *breakInterval* is called, look at the code below:

```
    // current state: *Session: 1min 10sec*
    this.breakInterval = setInterval(()=>{
      // No, condition is not satisfied, because current 
      // state is *Session: 1min 10sec*
      if(this.state.breakMin == 0 && this.state.Sec == 0){
        // ...clear breakInterval logic 
      }

      this.setState({
         // this.state.display will be 'Break'
        display: 'Break',
        // and this.state.Sec will be 9
        Sec: this.state.Sec == 0 ? 10 : this.state.Sec-1,
        // As mentioned above, current state is still **Session: 1min 
        // 10sec**, i.e. this.state.Sec is 10. So in 
        // ternary operator SECOND expression will be executed
        // breakMin: this.state.breakMin
        breakMin: this.state.Sec == 0 ? this.state.breakMin-1 : this.state.breakMin
      })

    },1000)
```

*breakMin* is initialized in constructor as 1

```
  this.state={
      display: 'Session',
      sessionMin: 2,
      sessionConst:2,
      // Yep, here
      breakMin: 1,
      breakConst: 1,
      Sec: 0,
    }
```

Voila! After **Session: 1min 10sec**, state of your timer is **Break: 1min 9sec** now. There are several problems here:

- After session interval *this.state.display* value is still *Session*
- The problem you voiced: incorrect number of minutes when *breakInterval* starts

Why after first cycle timer state **Session: 1min 10sec** changes to **Break: 0min 9sec**, i.e. number of minutes is correct? Frankly speaking, ***is not correct***.
So, after **Break: 1min 9sec** timer reached **Break: 0min 0sec**. Again, look at code below:

```
    // current state: Break: 0min 0sec**
    this.breakInterval = setInterval(()=>{
      // Yes, condition is satisfied
      if(this.state.breakMin == 0 && this.state.Sec == 0){
        // You tell a browser API "Stop calling this function in 
        // future", but current function execution continues !!!
        clearInterval(this.breakInterval)
        // this.state.breakMin is now 1
        this.setState({ breakMin: this.state.breakConst })
        console.log(this.state.breakMin)
        // this.handleTimer() is called, but this.interval()
        // will be called after 1000ms
        this.handleTimer()
      }

      this.setState({
        // this.state.display will be 'Break'
        display: 'Break',
        // this.state.Sec will be 10
        Sec: this.state.Sec == 0 ? 10 : this.state.Sec-1,
        // this.state.Sec is still 0, so in ternary operator 
        // FIRST expression will be executed
        // breakMin: this.state.breakMin - 1
        // Because current value of this.state.breakMin is 1,
        // result value will be 0 (1 - 1) !!!!!!!
        breakMin: this.state.Sec == 0 ? this.state.breakMin-1 : this.state.breakMin
      })

    },1000)
```

After execution of code above, actual value of *this.state.breakMin* will be **0, not 1**, and current state will be **Break: 0min 10sec**. After that, session interval will be called, state will be **Session: 1min 9sec**, the cycle will start again.
Let's say session interval reached **Session: 0min 0sec**. As you remeber, after that timer state will be **Session: 1min 10sec** (see the first code example). So:

```
    // **Session: 1min 10sec**
    this.breakInterval = setInterval(()=>{
      // No, condition is not satisfied
      if(this.state.breakMin == 0 && this.state.Sec == 0){
        // ...clear breakInterval logic 
      }

      this.setState({
        display: 'Break',
        // this.state.Sec will be 9
        Sec: this.state.Sec == 0 ? 10 : this.state.Sec-1,
        // this.state.Sec is 10, so in 
        // ternary operator SECOND expression will be executed
        // breakMin: this.state.breakMin
        // Beacause actual value of this.state.breakMin is 0,
        // new breakMin value will be zero too
        breakMin: this.state.Sec == 0 ? this.state.breakMin-1 : this.state.breakMin
      })

    },1000)
```

Therefore, after the first cycle the number of minutes is correct (although everything inside does not work quite as it should)

2. When you click Play button after first click, you call this.handleTimer method and create a second timer. Then, when you click Stop button, you clear second timer, but the first timer is still working! And you don't have possibility to stop first timer, because this.interval variable was overwritten by a new timer reference.

***So, the solution:***

```
class TypesOfFood extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      display: 'Session',
      paused: false,
      sec: 0,
      min: this.sessionMinutesConst,
    }
  }
  
  // use 9, not 10 for tests or 59, not 60 in "production"
  // it will be look like:
  // 2:01 -> 2:00 -> 1:59
  secondsInOneMinute = 9
  sessionMinutesConst = 2
  breakMinutesConst = 1
  
  timer = null
  
  decrementTimer = () => {
     this.setState(currentState => ({
        sec: currentState.sec === 0 ? this.secondsInOneMinute : currentState.sec - 1,
        min: currentState.sec === 0 ? currentState.min - 1 : currentState.min
      }))
  }
  
  createTimer = () => { 
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.handleTimer()
      this.decrementTimer()
    }, 1000)
  }
  
  handleTimer = () => {    
    const { sec, min } = this.state
    const isSessionTimer = this.state.display === 'Session'
    
    if (sec === 0 && min === 0) {
       this.setState({
         display: isSessionTimer ? 'Break' : 'Session',
         min: isSessionTimer ? this.breakMinutesConst : this.sessionMinutesConst
       })
    }
  }

  handleStop = () => {
    this.setState({ paused: true })
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  
  handleReset = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
    this.timer = null
    
    this.setState({
      display: 'Session',
      paused: false,
      sec: 0,
      min: this.sessionMinutesConst,
    })
  }
  
  handlePlay = () => {
    if (this.timer && !this.state.paused) return
    
    this.createTimer()
    this.setState({ paused: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <h3>{this.state.display}</h3>
        <h1>{this.state.min}m:{this.state.sec}s</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handlePlay}>Play</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleStop}>Stop</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What you should pay attention to:

- I replaced two timers with only one timer. When timer state is **[current timer]: 0min 0sec**, *this.state.display* and *this.state.min* changes to new values - Session or Break and this.sessionMinutesConst or this.breakMinutesConst respectively in *handleTimer* method.
- *timer* property in class. When timer is created, it's reference is asigned to this property, so it is easy to clear timer whenever we want
- *handleStop* method. I added *paused* property to the state, so it's easy to understand, when timer is stopped and when it is fully cleared
- *handlePlay* method. New timer is created only when there is no current timer or when there is current timer, but it is just paused.
- I removed your *binds* in constructor - it's not necessary when declaring methods as arrow functions
- I implemented *handleReset* method

Hope that helped!

Comment: Huge thanks for details explanation and giving your valuable time. I got to learn alot from you and clear lots of concept. Your code give me new dimension to resolve my problems. I am still not clear with why breaks length work after first cycle, but it gives me prespective why my implementation is wrong in so many ways. I will read your answer again again to clear my doubt.